# How to upload multiple images at once to Google Drive?

Tags: images, gallery, google-drive

I want to upload to Google Drive, all my image files that are within my gallery. At the moment I have to select the images one by one to do so.

Long pressing the images and the folders themselves does not open a context selection grid as it normally would.

I am using default gallery. I am also using the android 2.3.3 on an LG-P999-V21e.

Comment: Which Android version is your phone/tablet running? My Nexus 7 (on 4.1.2) does just that. Long press a folder in the Gallery app, select *Drive* as target, upload, done.

Comment: What app are you using? Default Gallery?

Answer (score 7):

Do not go to Google Drive directly.

1. Gallery
2. Select the files you want to Upload
3. Share (icon like Branch) -NOW you choose Google drive and folder... Click OK and you are in Business

Comment: can't believe there's _still_ no way to do this from within the Drive app itself smh

Comment: It seems the limitation is from the Android file picker -- you can't seem to select multiple items, and if you use Desktop mode from a browser at drive

Comment: Some time after reading this I discovered [programs like FolderSync or autosync](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207177/11706). I wouldn't use a method like this now, you can sync your entire phone in just a few taps to Google Drive or other services like Dropbox using FolderSync or Autosync.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, this is assuming you have ICS or higher (not sure if the Gallery works this way before then).

If you open an album, you should be able to long-press on a photo, and then at the top of the screen, where it says 1 selected, press that and you can say 'select all'.

Then upload them.

Comment: To be clear, this is via the gallery, not via the Drive app. Long-pressing does not work if you open the gallery via the Drive app. You need to select your photos then *share* it to a Drive folder.

Answer (score 1):

I have two alternative solutions for you.

## 1. Zip it

Make a zip archive (or RAR) of the multiple items you want to upload. Then upload only that file.

[image: make a zip archive of the multiple items you want to upload]

Zipping has the advantage of preserving LAST MODIFIED (folder uploads tend to not preserve that field)

## 2. Auto file sync tools

Alternatively, you may choose to use a 3rd party tool like FolderSync or Autosync to sync entire folders automatically and periodically in the background. This kind of gets you the usual Desktop backup behavior you might expect from Drive. Unfortunately the current version of their app won't do auto backups. Using FolderSync or Autosync will allow you to sync **entire folders easily** without having to tap-check each file you want to sync in the folder.

I **do not** recommend using the Drive app itself to upload multiple files at once (it gets very slow and heavy with 500+ items).

Answer (score 0):

This works on my S4, there is a maximum upload of 500 files per xfer.

Do not go to Google Drive directly.

Gallery
Select the files you want to Upload [press "1 selected box" to select all files or FOLDERS [DOES NOT UPLOAD FOLDERS...unfortunately].
Share (icon like Branch) -NOW you choose Google drive and folder... Click OK and files will upload [use WIFI for faster uploads]

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get around the situation would be if you could use a microSD card. Just copy all the images into it and use it in a newer phone or pc/mac and upload the images to Google Drive / Photos.

Answer (score 0):

I know the simplest way to upload multiplefiles to drive be it photos, your apps and their data, music's etc or whatever, is through your file manager. Say you want to upload all your apps, I use ES Explorer, I launch the app and select apps. Iong press on the apps I want to upload and tap share. From there I select save to Google drive. I am there directed to drive where I can edit the file names and change their location. That's all. This works too for folders even app data if only you know their directories

Answer (score 0):

This might help: On my Samsung A52 I could only 'select all' from the Gallery app, not just a few. Instead, go to the Samsung app folder, find 'My Files', select 'images', hit the 3 dots at the top, select 'share', and now you can choose which files you want to share. As soon as you select an image, or more, the share icon will pop up. and then you can share wherever.